# Editing connectors in Intellij class diagrams

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, class-diagram

I found out Intellij supports drawing a class diagram or generating it from a given source package. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html) for more details.
The default for a field is to draw a 1-1 Composition connector (and 1-* Composition connector for arrays).

Is there any way to edit the multiplicity and to change the connector type (For example set the relationship to (1-3 aggregation)?

I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram-toolbar-and-context-menu.html), except a declaration that "IntelliJ IDEA follows the UML conventions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in IntelliJ IDEA at the moment, you can [vote for the related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-46363).